# Python merge variables and text into new variable

Tags: python

so I have the line:

```
text="Temp :" + TempVar + "C CPUTemp: " + CPUTempVar + "C"
```

How would I get that to work as a string on text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) to create a string from your variables.

```
TempVar = 100
CPUTempVar = 50
text = 'Temp : {}C CPUTemp: {}C'.format(TempVar,CPUTempVar)

>>> text
'Temp : 100C CPUTemp: 50C'
```

Comment: In Python 2.6 and earlier, you'll need indexes in the format string: `'Temp : {0}C CPUTemp: {1}C'.format(TempVar,CPUTempVar)`. I know 2.6 is a bit long in the tooth now, and later versions don't need that much specification, but I still see a good deal of it in use, so any code I distribute widely, I put the indices in.

Answer (score 1):

I endorse @Cyber's answer (the `format` method) as the straightforward, modern Python way to format strings.

For completeness, however, the old way (common prior to Python 2.6) was a string interpolation operator:

```
text = 'Temp : %dC CPUTemp: %dC' % (TempVar,CPUTempVar)
```

It still works in the latest Python 3 releases, and will commonly be seen in older code.

Or you could use my [say](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/say) package to do inline string substitution (or printing) similar to what you'd expect from Ruby, Perl, PHP, etc.:

```
from say import *

text = fmt('Temp : {TempVar}C CPUTemp: {CPUTempVar}C')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast as strings if you want to concat non strings to strings:

```
TempVar = 100
CPUTempVar = 100
text="Temp: " + str(TempVar) + "C CPUTemp: " + str(CPUTempVar) + "C"

print(text)
Temp: 100C CPUTemp: 100C
```